# Can I hover over a div and change the attributes of the div before it?

Tags: html, css

I have several sibling divs lined up like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/geekongirl/Lahvkxf6/3/):

```css
div {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
div:hover {
    background-color: #b5b5b5;
}
 
/*color changes*/
.a:hover ~ .b {
   background-color: #E6E600;
}
.b:hover + .a {
    background-color: #ccffcc;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">Box A
</div>
<div>another box
</div>
<div>another box
</div>
<div>another box
</div>
<div class="b">Box B
</div>
```

Is there a way to make it so that when I hover over box b, box a's attributes change?

EDIT: I want to change "a"'s background color

Comment: There's no way using css. You may use jQuery.

Comment: jQuery is the way forward.

Comment: Clearly explain what you need to change for the A's attribute when B is hovered please.

Comment: I want to change A's background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".b").hover(
    function() {
      $(".a").addClass("c");
    }, function() {
      $(".a").removeClass("c");
    });
});
```

```css
.c {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">Box A</div>
<div>another box</div>
<div>another box</div>
<div>another box</div>
<div class="b">Box B</div>
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/hnvywLed/5/)

Answer (score 2):

here is an interesting way to do it

```
.rating {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: center;
}
.rating > span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1.1em;
}
.rating > span:hover,
.rating > span:hover ~ span {
  color: transparent;
}
.rating > span:hover:before,
.rating > span:hover ~ span:before {
   content: "\2605";
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   color: gold;
}


<div class="rating">
            <span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span>
        </div>
```

example : https://css-tricks.com/examples/StarRating/

Comment: amazed of upvotes that answer is outside the question scope.

Comment: Interesting, how do you change the chars order back? i.e. word > drow > word.